# Validate XML against a schema having any element

Tags: schema, xml-validation

I have a schema say called BPMN20.xsd having an element called extensionElements.see sample below:

```
<xsd:element name="extensionElements" type="tExtensionElements" /> 
    <xsd:complexType name="tExtensionElements">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /> 
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Now the xml contains elements inside extensionElements, which conform to another schema say ufl.xsd. Example:

```
<extensionElements>
    <ufl:java method="calculate"
            class="com.companyx.orchestration.bpmn.ordermanagement.data.CalculateOrderAmount">
                    <ufl:arg type="com.companyx.orchestration.bpmn.ordermanagement.data.OrderLine"
                        var="item" />
                </ufl:java>
</extensionElements>
```

Now i want to validate my XML against both the schemas. How to do this ? 
If i just validate my xml against BPMN20.xsd it works (since content if extensionElements is defined as any. However i also want to validate the contents inside extensionElements against ufl.xsd

Please help...

Thanks,
Siddharth

Answer (score 0):

Use processContents as lax in the schema where you defined the any element.
This will enforce the converter in finding the schema element for the passed xml.